# How to specify non linear regression model in python

Tags: scipy, regression, statsmodels, non-linear-regression, scipy-optimize

I am taking an Econometrics course, and have been trying to use Python rather than the propreitry STATA and EVIEWS they set the assignments in.

In one of the questions, I have consumption data over time. I am asked to compute it in two ways.

The first way is calculating a model of the form consumption = Aexp(Bt), and the second way is to log both sides and do ordinary OLS on log(consumption) = alpha + Bt

I know how to do the second way. Howver, when I try to do the first way it goes wrong. Using statsmodels, I can exponentiate the time data (after normalising), but this calculates a regression in the form consumption = Aexp(t) + B, which is not what I want. (I want to specify where the parameters go). In sklearn I could find a polynomial regression, but not exponential.

Then I found scipy.curve_fit 
However this seems to have two problems:
(1) It seems to rely on initial guesses for parameters, which means my output will end up being different from proprietry software (whereas output for things like OLS are the same) [as I assume initial guesses means some iterative solution is done which is helpful for very weird and wonderful functions, but I assume fairly standard results hold for exponential regression]
(2) every time I try to implement it, it just returns the guess parameters.

Here is my code

```
`consumption_data = pd.read_csv(......\consumption.csv")
def func(x,a,b):
    return a * np.exp(b*x)

xdata = consumption_data.YEAR
ydata = consumption_data.CONSUMPTION
ydata = (ydata - 1948)/100

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, (1,1))
print(popt)

plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'g--',)
`
```

The scipy.optimize code is basically just copy-pasted from their tutorial
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Answer (score 0):

**short answer:** use statsmodels `GLM`

statsmodels does not have nonlinear least squares. The best python library for that is lmfit https://pypi.org/project/lmfit/

`curve_fit`, `lmfit` and nonlinear least squares algorithm in general find an iterative solution to the optimization problem. Even when we have to provide starting values, the solution is in many cases the same across packages up to convergence tolerance, e.g. 1e-5 or 1e-6.
Many standard models in statistics and econometrics have a single global maximum with well behaved data. However, in other cases like mixture models, there might be many local optima and the estimation might converge to one of them.

To the specific case:

`consumption = A exp(B t)`
can be rewritten as
`consumption = exp(a + B t)`

So this is just a single index model or a generalized linear model with an exponential mean function.

The general version has the expectation of the dependent variable as a nonlinear function of a linear combination of the explanatory variables:

E(y | x) = g(x b)

This can be estimated with statsmodels with GLM with family Gaussian and the log-link.

Aside: In econometrics, there is a literature to use Poisson quasi-likelihood as an estimator for `exp` models instead of taking the log of the dependent variable.
Poisson usually uses the log-link function as in the above.

However, using GLM allows us to use log-link, i.e. exponential mean function, with any of the supported distribution families. The main difference is in the underlying variance assumption. Gaussian assumes constant variance, Poisson assumes that the variance is proportional to the mean and Gamma assumes that the variance is quadratic in the mean.

If we use a robust sandwich covariance estimator for parameter inference, then standard errors and inference are correct even if the variance function is misspecified.